# Tumblr API: 'Cannot read property 'alt_sizes' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, tumblr

I am trying to implement a photo feed using the Tumblr API. So far it works with just text, but when I try photos I get the error

`Cannot read property 'alt_sizes' of undefined`

I am not sure how to go about correcting my code to fix this. My code is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=key&tag=offers",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){

    var i = 0;

     while (i < 10) {

       var type = results.response.posts[i].type;
       var date = results.response.posts[i].date;
       var link = results.response.posts[i].post_url;

       if (type == "photo") {
         var photourl = results.response.posts[i].photos[i].alt_sizes[i].url;
         $("#tumoffers").append("<div class='tumpost'><a href='" + link + "'><img src='" + photourl + "' alt='" + title + "'/></a></div>");
       }

      i++;
     }//END WHILE

    }//END RESULTS FUNCTION
});
```

Looking at the Tumblr API documentation I see that `alt_sizes` translates to the size of the image, but I dont want to use this attribute.

Does anyone know how to make the API ignore this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it was getting an error because you can have multiple photos per post, so the lines

`.photos[i].alt_sizes[i]`

are actually in a different array, within the main posts array.

In my case I was only using 1 photo per post, so I simply changed it to

`.photos[0].alt_sizes[0]`

but to do it correctly you should create another loop for the photos per post.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check if such property exists before actually trying to access it, like:

```
var data = results.response,
    i = results.response.total_posts; //this gives total posts you have
while (i < 10) {
    var type = data.posts[i].type,
        date = data.posts[i].date,
        link = data.posts[i].post_url;

   if( "photo" == type ) {
        if( data.posts[i].hasOwnProperty("alt_sizes") {
           var photourl = results.response.posts[i].photos[i].alt_sizes[i].url;
           $("#tumoffers").append("<div class='tumpost'><a href='" + link + "'><img src='" + photourl + "' alt='" + title + "'/></a></div>");
        }
   }
   i++;
}
```